# Is my front derailleur angled straight?

Tags: mountain-bike, chain, gears, derailleur

I am attempting to adjust my front gears and have also been following a video to adjust the high/low position of my front derailleur.

The issue I am having is that the low adjustment is no where near the 2mm distance that the chain to front derailleur should attain. The photos below also show the distance I can achieve.

Now I am wondering; 
**Is the angle of my front derailleur is incorrect?** If so, what should I line it up with?

I have supplied a couple of photos. Please feel free to ask for additional info.

The photo was taken while the the rear gear was on the biggest cog and the front gear was on the smallest cog. The chain is almost touching the front, pedal side of the derailleur and the chain is almost touching the derailleur at the back on the frame side.

thank you

[View from the top - Click for larger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Trb4o.jpg)
[image]

[View from the rear tyre forward. Click for larger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4e145.jpg)

[image]

Comment: There are subtleties, but as a first approximation the arm of the derailer should be parallel to the sprockets.  Yours appears to be rotated forward a bit too much.

Comment: You may want to resize your pics. They are difficult to see the overview on a normal sized monitor.

Comment: @kenbike: yes. ty, and i have changed the img.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That derailleur appears to be rotated so that the "tail" of the derailleur plate is too far from the frame.

The ideal is to have the inside plate be parallel to the chain rings, and have the bottom edge of the outer derailleur plate be between 1 and 2 mm above the top edge of the large chain ring teeth, while there is no cable attached, or it is shifted to the smallest front sprocket.

The image below is Park Tool's description of proper alignment.

[image: Park tool image of derailleur alignment]

Comment: thank you. After many adjustments using this lining. My gears are adjusting properly and my chain is not overshooting and going off the cog.